# Sceneform plane rendering similar to the HelloAR sample

Tags: android, augmented-reality, arcore, sceneform

I was trying to cover the whole surface of the detected plane with a texture. Using OpenGl (like in the [HelloAr](https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk/tree/master/samples/hello_ar_java) sample) enables me do this like this [screenshot](https://prntscr.com/kghjm6)  . However i want to switch to Sceneform and i only could get something like [this](https://prntscr.com/kghk6g) by following other questions in the Github.
These are the codes that i used currently for texture rendering. To conclude, i do not want this spotlight texture on the plane. I want to cover whole detected plane like my first screenshot. Can you give some information about how can i achieve this? Thank you!

```
 Texture.Sampler sampler =
            Texture.Sampler.builder()
                    .setMagFilter(Texture.Sampler.MagFilter.LINEAR)
                    .setMinFilter(Texture.Sampler.MinFilter.LINEAR)
                    .setWrapMode(Texture.Sampler.WrapMode.REPEAT)
                    .build();

    CompletableFuture<Texture> trigrid = Texture.builder()
            .setSource(this, R.drawable.gray)
            .setSampler(sampler).build();

    PlaneRenderer planeRenderer = arSceneView.getPlaneRenderer();
    planeRenderer.getMaterial().thenAcceptBoth(trigrid, (material, texture) -> {
        material.setTexture(PlaneRenderer.MATERIAL_TEXTURE, texture);
    });`
```

Comment: I'm trying to make the same on my code to test, but is crashing on the setSource, can you show a little more where you put this part of the code? Until there, one suggestion, did you tried to make gray more transparent? like: #78ABABAB

Comment: Actually gray is just a 8x8 gray rectangle image. These codes are just after the setting the arscene at onCreate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution both using other answers and combine them. Proper plane rendering can be done like below. Important point is this renderable should be called at every frame otherwise ARCore overrides it and you don't see the effect that you want. Here is a code that solves my problem.

```
arSceneView.getScene().addOnUpdateListener(frameTime -> {
            PlaneRenderer planeRenderer = arSceneView.getPlaneRenderer();
            planeRenderer.getMaterial().thenAcceptBoth(trigrid, (material, texture) -> {
                material.setTexture(PlaneRenderer.MATERIAL_TEXTURE, texture);
                material.setFloat(PlaneRenderer.MATERIAL_SPOTLIGHT_RADIUS, Float.MAX_VALUE);
            });

});
```

Comment: Thank you, sir. It works. But distance need to set as 10 - 100f.

Answer (score 3):

You can control the radius of the spotlight on the material. To make the spotlight effect go away, you can set the radius to a large number:

```
planeRenderer.getMaterial().thenAcceptBoth(trigrid, (material, texture) -> {
    material.setTexture(PlaneRenderer.MATERIAL_TEXTURE, texture);
    material.setFloat(PlaneRenderer.MATERIAL_SPOTLIGHT_RADIUS,1000);
});
```

Comment: I set the radius to the Float.MAX_VALUE however renderer changes with the camera movement. I mean if plane is big then it still showed up as spotlight. What i need is like something in my first screenshot.

Comment: Thank you, @ClaytonWilkinson. Your solution helps for us.

Answer (score 0):

From [this](https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk/issues/48#issuecomment-393595309), probably is the size of your texture that are a little strange.

Change the **MATERIAL_UV_SCALE** parameter. This parameter is used to control the size at which the texture.

```
planeRenderer.getMaterial()
.thenAcceptBoth(trigrid, (material, texture) -> {
    material.setTexture(PlaneRenderer.MATERIAL_TEXTURE, texture);
    material.setFloat2(PlaneRenderer.MATERIAL_UV_SCALE, 50.0f, 50.0f);

});
```

Comment: Unfortunately it still gives me that spotlight effect rather than covering whole plane. I tried to change my raw texture but still no luck. Also the post that you have linked still gets circular render if you looked closely, i want more polygonic plane like my first screenshot